# excel: how do i break up cell contents into CODE

Tags: excel, ascii, worksheet-function

There is a code function that returns ASCII for every letter.

I would like to use it in a way that it will break up a cell `a1 = "some string"`

Into it's ASCII codes:

Something like this: "`23423423434634`"

Sorry I don't know the exact ASCII of that but you get my point.

please note that i would like to do this specifically with a formula and NOT with VBA

Comment: altered my answer in response to your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a Byte Array to give Unicode number pairs for each character:

```
Sub ByteArray()
    Dim aByte() As Byte
    Dim str1 As String<
    Dim j As Long
    str1 = "ABC"
    aByte = str1
    For j = LBound(aByte) To UBound(aByte)
        MsgBox aByte(j)
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: please note that i would like to do this specifically with a formula and NOT with VBA

Answer (score 1):

Write an Excel [User Defined Function](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/Functions.htm#UDFIntro).

Pseudocode for the function is below:

```
string returnValue;
for each ( char c in string)
   returnValue = returnValue + Chr(char)
return returnValue
```

You can call the [UDF](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/Functions.htm#UDFIntro) as part of an excell formula eg

```
=StringToASCIICodeValues(A1)
```

---

### Formula Version

You could do it manually with excel builtin formula's by (*excel doesn't have a for-loop function for formulae*)

1. A1="some string"
2. A2="=MID($A$1,COLUMN(A2),1)"
3. Drag the formula in cell A2 to the right.  Drag to K2 for `some string` example.
4. A3="=CODE(A2)"
5. Drag the formula in cell A3 to the right. Drag to K3 for `some string` example.
6. A4="=A3"
7. B4="=CONCATENATE(A4,B3)"
8. Drag the formula in cell B4 to the right. Drag to Cell K4 for `some string` example.
9. The right most column with a value on row 4 contains the final value.  For `some string` it will return: `11511110910132115116114105110103` in cell K4

Comment: please note that i would like to do this specifically with a formula and NOT with VBA

Comment: @jenny now produced a way to do it only using formulas. As far as I know excel can't do it in a 1-step process with out VBA

Answer (score 0):

```
    string someText = "some string";
    CharEnumerator ce = someText.GetEnumerator();
    int counter = 0;
    while (ce.MoveNext())
    {
        char letter = someText[counter];
        //Call the function to get the ascii
        GetAsciiValue(letter);
        //Do something

        counter++;
    }
```

May be this might help you.

Regards, J'Sinh

Answer (score 0):

Although it's ugly, if your strings are not too long you can do it with a long formula which converts each character and then joins them back together.

For example this formula can handle strings which are up to 20 characters in length (creating hex ascii codes):

```
=if(len(A1)>=1,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,1,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=2,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,2,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=3,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,3,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=4,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,4,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=5,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,5,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=6,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,6,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=7,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,7,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=8,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,8,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=9,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,9,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=10,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,10,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=11,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,11,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=12,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,12,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=13,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,13,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=14,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,14,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=15,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,15,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=16,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,16,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=17,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,17,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=18,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,18,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=19,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,19,1))),"")&
if(len(A1)>=20,DEC2HEX(CODE(MID(A1,20,1))),"")
```

For longer strings you could repeat this pattern, although you'd be limited by the maximum formula length allowed by Excel, [which seems to be 8,192 characters](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#bmcalculation).